# Facebook live app automatically returns onCancel in loginManager

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

In app I'm using login by Facebook, and when my account was marked as test user everything works great. But when I try to login by normal user my permission request automatically returns onCancel. On test user facebook show window with permissions which I need but on normal user window doesn't appear.

Someone know how to fix this ?

My code to login:

```
override fun facebookLoginAndPermissions(loginButton: LoginButton, activity: LoginActivity, callbackManager: CallbackManager, loginManager: LoginManager) {

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(arrayListOf("user_events"))

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
            val accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
            if (accessToken != null) {
                if (accessToken.permissions?.contains("rsvp_event")!!) {
                    mvpView?.changeActivity()
                } else {
                   facebookPermission(activity,callbackManager,loginManager)
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            Log.d("LoginPresenter", "facebookLoginError ${error?.message}")
        }
        override fun onCancel() {
            Log.d("LoginPresenter", "facebookLoginCancel")
        }
    })
}


 override fun facebookPermission(activity: LoginActivity, callbackManager: CallbackManager, loginManager: LoginManager){
    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(activity, arrayListOf("rsvp_event"))
    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            Log.d("LoginPresenter", "fbPermission: ${error?.message}")
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            mvpView?.onFacebookPermissionDeclined() <------- THIS IS RETURN WHEN I TRY TO GET USER PERMISSIONS
        }

        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
            mvpView?.changeActivity()
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Did you get your app’s use of those permissions reviewed by Facebook already …? That is a requirement before you can ask normal users for those permissions.

Comment: @CBroe no I don't. I will do this, thanks :D